# Extra margin on side of an image inside table-cell in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, webkit

```
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='innerWrapper'>
     <img src ='image.png'" />
  </div>
</div>

#wrapper{
  display: table;
  border-spacing:0;
}

#innerWrapper {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
}
img {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   border:0;
}
```

In Chrome, this renders a 1px margin on right side of the image and pushes innerWrapper div out. How to remove the margin? CSS reset did not help

Comment: Are you able to create a fiddle please?

Comment: The code posted, when tested on Chrome 24beta, does not demonstrate the problem described in the text at all-

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<div id='innerWrapper'><img src ='image.png'" /></div>
```

Without the line breaks in the source?

Comment: that could help since a line break is interpreted as a space in html

Answer (score 0):

Reset the margins for all DIVs on the page:

```
div { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```